# geoAlbersUSA Projection not mapping as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-science

I am having some issues using the d3.geoAlbersUsa() projection for a given set of latitudes and longitudes from [here](https://github.com/sughodke/D3-US-Graph/blob/master/nationalparks.csv)

I basically have my entire code below, I feel as if there is an issue with the specific projection of (lat, long) to the right projection. It's strange as I followed the instructions from [the package I am using to generate the actual map](https://github.com/topojson/us-atlas) (topojson-us-atlas)

Here is a snapshot of the documentation from topojson-us-atlas package
[image]

This is what it looks like now:

[image: misplaced park dots]

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@3"></script>
    
    <title>National Parks in GeoAlbersUSA Projection</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>

    body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>




<header>
 <h1>World Map Visualization of National Parks</h1>
</header>


  <svg width="960" height="500" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></svg>

  <script>

    var svg = d3.select("svg");
    var path = d3.geoPath();    

    d3.json("https://unpkg.com/us-atlas@1/us/10m.json", function(error, us) {
      if (error) throw error;

      svg.append("path")
          .attr("stroke", "#aaa")
          .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
          .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties, function(a, b) { return a !== b && (a.id / 1000 | 0) === (b.id / 1000 | 0); })));

      svg.append("path")
          .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
          .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })));

      svg.append("path")
          .attr("d", path(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.nation)));
    });

    d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codebrotherone/2days/master/data/locations.csv', function(d){
        var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa();


        var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(d)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("cx",function(d) {return parseFloat(projection([d.longitude, d.latitude]));
           })
          .attr("cy",function(d) { return parseFloat(projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1]);
           })
          .attr("r", 1)
          .attr("fill", 'red')

      });


  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone see or spot anything amiss?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The topojson outline of the US is projected with a projection that isn't the default d3.geoAlbersUsa - the topojson is projected into a box 960x600, whereas the default d3.geoAlbersUsa settings project the US into a box 960 x 500 - you need to modify the translate and scale factors when projecting your points: https://jsfiddle.net/bze197L2/

Comment: First off. Thank you! You are a beast at answering these questions ;) 

I understand the scale portion perfectly. Why do you translate though? wondering where you got the 480 and 300 from.

Comment: The translate of a d3 map projection is generally: [width/2,height/2] (the main exception is when zooming/panning) - this is the value used when Mike projected the topojson to a 960x600 pixel space. So we have to modify the Albers projection so that we match the projection used by Mike with a translate of [960/2,600/2].

Comment: Perfect explanation. If I could give more than 1 upvote I would. Thanks!